# Passing multiple variables from servlet to client

Tags: gwt, servlets

I hope someone can assist me with this. I'm trying to pass an customer id and customer name from a database result using rpc in gwt to the client. I found a way to pass one variable but I can't find a way to pass them both where the id is attached to the name. Can someone post a code example on how to do this. If you need more info let me know.

Comment: How are servlets involved in the story? What code do you have as far and where exactly are you stucking? (please only post **relevant** snippets, not complete rags).

Comment: Was your question really "How do I return more than one value from a Java method?" as the answers seem to suggest? Honestly, I don't see that clearly back in your question, it would otherwise have been a very obvious answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is a simple java limitation. Just wrap the 2 fields in an object.

Comment: I figured the problem out. I placed the data into json and converted it to a string and pass it to the client. I then parse the string and pulled the data out on the client side. This allowed me to pass as many variables as I need from the server to the client.

Answer (score 1):

As David Nouls said, you could just use an object, e.g.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public class Customer implements IsSerializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```